# Ingress rule is not created in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform to create resources in AWS. All resources get created. The only object that is not created is the ingress rule on the security group. Below is the terraform code block to create the security group:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "my_security_group" {
  name = "my-security-group"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_module_vpc.id
  ingress {
    description = "All inbound traffic"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

When I check in AWS console, the security group is created with egress rule but not the ingress rule. Any pointers why ingress rule is not created?

Comment: I'm able to create both inbound and outbound rules successfully with your TF code. Please check once again and come up with precise issue or the error message if any.

Comment: Thanks @Ravichandran fir the response. It still does not work for me. It only works if I create the ingress rule as a separate Terraform object and then attach it to the security group. No errors in any case.

Comment: Please share your entire code and debug log in github or gist. Let me take a look. Please ensure no sensitive data in it.